# Maximum eigenvalue of a hollow symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is the maximum eigenvalue (or spectral radius) of the matrix with the following form equalled to row or column sum of the matrix?

$$
A=\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & a & ... & a \\
a & 0 & ... & a \\
: & : & ...& :  \\
a & a & ... & 0\end{array} \right) $$

The matrix is square with dimension $n \times n$ where $n = 2,3,4,...$, hollow (all elements in the principal diagonal = 0), symmetric and all off diagonal elements have the same value.

Is the spectral radius of such matrices = $(n-1)\times a$? Why?

Comment: The eigenvalues of such a matrix can be completely identified, and they have been in a number of previous Questions.

Comment: Thanks hardmath - can you give a pointer/link to such answers? I searched but didn't find. Thanks.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the link. It's indeed very useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the matrix $A$ of all $a$'s, whose eigenvalues are zero except for eigenvalue $na$ having multiplicity one (because rank$(A) = 1$).

Now subtract $aI$ from $A$ to get your matrix.  The eigenvalues of $A-aI$ are those of $A$ shifted down by $a$.  We get a eigenvalue $(n-1)a$ of multiplicity one and eigenvalue $-a$ with multiplicity $n-1$.

So the spectral radius (largest absolute value of an eigenvalue) of $A$ is $|na|$, and the spectral radius of $A-aI$ is $\max(|(n-1)a|,|a|)$.  The latter is simply $|(n-1)a|$ unless $n=1$.

Comment: For $A$ of all $a$'s, if we get n-1 eigenvalues = zero, and one eigenvalue = na, then shouldn't the eigenvalues of the "shifted" matrix $A-aI$ being $-a$ with multiplicity $(n-1)$ and $(n-1)a$ with multiplicity 1?

Comment: I was mistaken in my subtraction!  See my edit.